# Architecture of notification system in redis

Tags: redis

I have a user notifications system. It is possible to send a personal notification to user by id or send a broadcast message to all users (for example, about new feature). Now it is implemented as a single table in database with a structure like

```
<message_id, message_time, user_id, text, is_broadcast>
```

and operations:

- Insert message for user
- Fetch X messages for user Y to display and remove them from database (to not to display second time)
- Insert the same message for every user (broadcast message)
- Remove all broadcast messages that are older than N days (to not to keep broadcast messages for users that are not logged in for a long time, but personal messages are not removed)

Now I'm thinking about moving the whole messaging system from MySQL to Redis but I'm having an issue with choosing valid Redis data structures. I had an idea to create a list/set of messages for each user. It is fine with personal messaging but if I have a broadcast message I'll need to iterate for all lists and put a message there. The same issue is with removing old broadcast messages - I'll need to iterate for all lists and remove old messages. Are there any approaches that will make it easier?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the 2 types of message should be treated separately.

Perhaps store all broadcast messages in a single sorted set, where the sort score is the timestamp. This makes it easy to ZRANGE to fetch the latest, and ZREMRANGEBYSCORE to remove all broadcast messages older than N days. Then, to achieve a per-user pseudo read/unread status for broadcast messages, you could store for each user the score (timestamp) which they have read up to. (use ZRANGE .. WITHSCORES when fetching to get the timestamp too)

Then to handle personal messages, use a per-user list. You can LPUSH for insert, and LRANGE and LTRIM to fetch and remove X messages for the user.

Cons: lack of proper per-broadcast per-user read/unread status. Pros: avoids storing the same broadcast for every user.